# Let $PQR$ be a triangle. Let $f(x, y) = ax + by + c$. Let $A$ be a point inside $\Delta PQR$. Prove that $f(A) \le \max\{f(P), f(Q), f(R)\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $PQR$ be a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $f(x, y) = ax + by + c$. Let $A$ be a point inside $\Delta PQR$ (perimeter included). Prove that
$$f(A) \le \max\{f(P), f(Q), f(R)\}$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_programming

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, $f(A)>f(P)$ implies $\langle (a,b),P-A\rangle<0$, also  $\langle (a,b),Q-A\rangle<0$,  $\langle (a,b),R-A\rangle<0$. That is, $P.Q.R$ are in the same open halfplane with respect to the line orthogonal to $(a,b)$ through $A$, but then $A$ is exterior.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is in the interior of $PQR$ the level line $\{(x,y)\>|\>f(x,y)=f(A)\}$ separates the three points. It follows that there is a point $B\in\{P,Q,R\}$ with $f(B)>f(A)$, and similarly a point $C\in\{P,Q,R\}$ with $f(C)<f(A)$.